# Access97 LEFT JOIN SELECT

Tags: sql, ms-access-97

I'm stuck with some access97 sql,

```
SELECT Master.Text, Sub.Cnt
FROM Master
INNER JOIN [
SELECT Number, COUNT(*) As Cnt FROM SubTable GROUP BY Number]. AS Sub
ON Master.Number=Sub.Number
WHERE Master.Number=1;
```

Behaves as I would expect however Where I need to square bracket the 'SubTable' Name I recieve an error in FROM clause highlighting GROUP

```
SELECT Master.Text, Sub.Cnt
FROM Master
INNER JOIN [
SELECT Number, COUNT(*) As Cnt FROM [Sub Table] GROUP BY Number]. AS Sub
ON Master.Number=Sub.Number
WHERE Master.Number=1;
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets look really strange in the query.  Try using regular parentheses for the subquery:

```
SELECT Master.Text, Sub.Cnt
FROM Master INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT Number, COUNT(*) As Cnt
      FROM [Sub Table]
      GROUP BY Number
     ) AS Sub
     ON Master.Number = Sub.Number
WHERE Master.Number = 1;
```

EDIT:

You can rewrite this query as:

```
SELECT Master.Text, COUNT(*) as Cnt
FROM Master INNER JOIN 
     [Sub Table] as sub
     ON Master.Number = Sub.Number
WHERE Master.Number = 1
GROUP BY Number;
```

Comment: The square brackets are a weird thing that the Access query designer does.

Comment: @Gordon Square brackets are the correct notation for a97, the initial query functions correctly, it is in situations where there is a space in the tablename the problem occurs

Comment: @robpws . . . Yucch.  Why are you using software that was out of date over a decade ago?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's an old commercial product which apparently doesn't warrant the time to update